# How to install two server MySQL in the same machine

Tags: mysql

How to install two server MySQL in the same machine in order to test replication on MySQL?

Comment: did you try using diffrnt locations ?

Comment: yeah I tried i used diffrnt port of communication the first one 3306 the second 3305, the second time tried to use the same version of MySQL but i found at the end that the first one replaced by the second

Comment: if You have a link, documentation thank you for sharing it

Comment: I suppose the manual chapter titled [Running Multiple MySQL Instances on One Machine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/multiple-servers.html) is a bit too obvious?

Comment: I already use this but when i install the server when i want to install it the second time it replaced it it doesn't create another folder on my disc local

Comment: I install mysql(port 3307) with easyPHP(port 3306) but i found that the mysql in easyPHP doesn't start i don't know why exactly